# Amazon Athena Data process and schedule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

Need help

In AWS Athena we have few csv files stored in S3 and I have External table which using in Reporting
but after some calculations like aggregation or remove duplication etc

Now we will be updating the excel csv's regularly(new data) and how can I get this update automatically picked/scheduled and reports show latest with calculations which I created new table with CTAS

so how can do insert into this new CTAS table from  new S3 (csv files)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When a table is created in Amazon Athena, a `location` (directory) in Amazon S3 is specified.

When a query is run in Amazon Athena, it will **look in all files in that directory** (including sub-directories).

Therefore, the easiest way to add/update data in Amazon Athena is to **add/replace files in Amazon S3**, in the directory associated with the table. Any query will then use those new files. If you want to add *additional* data, simply add new data files. If you want to *replace* the existing data, simply upload a new file with the same name as the old file.

This process works slightly differently if you use `CREATE TABLE AS` (CTAS) -- it will store the data in a new location (which you can optionally specify). I find it easier to simply create the table once, then replace the data files as necessary.

Comment: No I am doing some calculations and some data coming from different database so need to update all in CTAS table then use it in reporting, so even one source got new data need to update corresponding tables

Comment: Think  I want to know  is, will event bridge or lamda or glue can trigger once new data added in S3 or in dymano tables then I got sql script to merge the CTAS table , will it work or best other solutions?

Comment: Yes, you can create a [trigger on Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/NotificationHowTo.html) that triggers when new objects are created, and [on DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) when data is added/changed. However, you would need to write your own logic that responds to such a trigger. This could be complex because adding multiple files or adding multiple items in DynamoDB would trigger multiple times, and you do not want to re-run the Athena queries for _every_ trigger (could be many per second).

Comment: Thanks John Yes it will be bit complex and thinking of Python or shell script as well